# Как прочитать шестнадцатеричные числа из консоли в массив байтов и затем вывести их?

Tags: c#, консоль, системы-счисления, байты

Ввожу шестнадцатеричное число к примеру: **0xA1 0x02**  и хочу вывести их в консоль.

Но увы не выходит :-(

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

struct Message
{    
    public byte[] setMessage; 
}

class TrimTram1
{
    public static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Тестовая прога.");
            // передача данных в структуру
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", message.setMessage.toString);
        }
}
```

Вот вывод:

```
mono tehn1_old.exe 
Тестовая прога.
0xA10x01
System.Byte[]
```

Нужно вместо `System.Byte[]` вывести введенные числа в таком же формате.

Прочел книгу 
[c# and game programming a beginner's guide](https://www.crcpress.com/C-and-Game-Programming-A-Beginners-Guide/Buono/p/book/9781568812366) Но увы там вообще с с массивом байтов не работают :( так и не понял почему.

Comment: `// вот тут ошибка !!!!` Что за ошибка-то? Какой должен быть вывод? Вообще, в вопросе много кода, не относящегося к вопросу (номер кадра, флаги и пр.), желательно бы его убрать.

Comment: @defaultlocale извините,  убрал всё лишнее

Comment: @timob256 Что-то не все, для демонстрации достаточно одного поля `setMessage`. И все-таки, в каком формате нужно вывести числа? В таком же как и введены (`0xA10x01`)? Обязательно чтобы они вводились без пробелов?

Comment: @defaultlocale да желательно, в том же виде, можно с пробелами можно без.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подход не совсем правильный. Метод

```
Console.ReadLine
```

считывает не байты, а строку из восьми символов: `0xA10x01`. Соответственно, код:

```
UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
```

преобразовывает строку в байтовое представление в кодировке UTF-8. А именно, он берет каждый символ введенной строки («0», «x», «A», «1» и т.д.) и преобразует каждый из них в один или несколько байтов.

У Вас, насколько я понял, задача другая:

- Нужно принять от пользователя несколько байтов в виде строк в шестнадцатеричном представлении.
- Преобразовать эти строки в массив байтов.
- Вывести массив байтов в таком же виде.

Стандартного способа сразу читать байты в таком представлении из консоли я не нашел. Поэтому строку понадобится парсить самому. Можно для этого написать два дополнительных метода: для преобразования строки в массив байтов и наоборот.

Формат предлагаю оставить таким же, только добавить пробелы для разделения символов:

```
class TrimTram1
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Тестовая прога.");
        //преобразовываем введенную строку в байты
        var message = new Message {setMessage = StringToByteArray(Console.ReadLine())};
        //преобразовываем байты в строку
        Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(message.setMessage));
    }

    private static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return hex.Split().Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s.Replace("0x", ""), 16)).ToArray();
    }

    private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] arr)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", arr.Select(b => $"0x{b:X2}"));
    }
}
```

Если вводить байты через пробел, то на входе и выходе получатся такие же значения.

По коду видно, что преобразование строки в байт выполняется через [`Convert.ToByte`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_). Байт же в строку преобразуется с помощью [спецификатора `X`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#the-hexadecimal-x-format-specifier).

Код написан на основе: [How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

P.S. Формат ввода можно улучшить. Например, избавиться от лишних `0x` и вводить байты одной строкой `A101`. Тогда из кода можно будет убрать лишние `Split` и `Replace`.